# How to integrate Google login on a CakePHP REST API

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, jwt, google-signin

I am building an Android app that is interfaced with a CakePHP 3 web API. Since a RESTful API cannot rely on cookies, I understand that I need JSON web tokens (JWT) to make this happen, and would much prefer to use a google login. I already got the Android side to request a token from Google's API, but now I am lost on how to incorporate this into my API for authentication.

I've searched around for some tutorials, such as this one: http://blog.jainsiddharth21.com/2013/04/29/login-with-google-in-cakephp/, but it relies on session data. I'm building the API in CakePHP 3, so I've looked at some of the plugins, such as [ADmad/JwtAuth](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth), so maybe I could extend on this to allow google authentication, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Please look at this link https://github.com/hareshpatel1990/cakephp3restapi hope this will help you...

Comment: A proper rest API wont use a session, therefore you need to send some kind of authentication along with each request, JWT is the best way to accomplish this!

Comment: @HareshKumar That is from the same tutorial I linked to, and anyway, I followed it exactly and it generates the tokens, but authentication still fails when I have the header `Authorization: Bearer my-long-token-here`.

Answer (score 4):

**Login With Gmail and Specific email address to allowed to login in CakePHP 3.x**

Composer to install

```
"google/apiclient": "^2.0"
```

Required gmail with login

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=mdpms-187410&organizationId=1095988912954

Create project and create secret key and client id

Project in set name and redirect URL

NOTE:- redirect URL must be .com and .org domain
If you develop in local machine then create follow type of virtual host
            example.com and example.org

Virtual host create then
Follow this step:

Set configuration file in app_globle.php

```
'Google' => 
[
        'googleClientID' => '123456.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'googleClientSecret' => 'abcdefghi',
        'googleRedirectUrl' => 'http://example.com/oauth2callback'
    ]
```

**Gmail login route**

//Google login

```
$routes->connect('/account/google-login', ['controller' => 'Account', 'action' => 'googlelogin'], ['_name' => 'account-google-login']);


$routes->connect('/oauth2callback', ['controller' => 'Account', 'action' => 'confirmlogin'], ['_name' => 'account-google-redirect-url']);
```

**Google login action code:**

```
 /**
 * Gmail login method
 */

    public function googlelogin()
    {


$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.googleClientID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.googleClientSecret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.googleRedirectUrl'));
    $client->se

tScopes([
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]);
        $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $this->redirect($url);
    }
```

**Google redirect url Action**

/**
     * Gmail auth redirect action
     * @return type gmail auth data
     */

```
 public function confirmlogin()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.googleClientID'));
        $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.googleClientSecret'));
        $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.googleRedirectUrl'));
        $client->setScopes([
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]);
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        if (isset($this->request->query['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($this->request->query['code']);
            $this->request->Session()->write('access_token', $client->getAccessToken());
        }
        if ($this->request->Session()->check('access_token') && ($this->request->Session()->read('access_token'))) {
            $client->setAccessToken($this->request->Session()->read('access_token'));
        }
        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $this->request->Session()->write('access_token', $client->getAccessToken());
            $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
            $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
            try {
                if (!empty($user)) {
                    if ((preg_match("/(@example\.com)$/", $user['email'])) || (preg_match("/(@example\.in)$/", $user['email']))) {
                        $result = $usersTable->find('all')
                                ->where(['email' => $user['email']])
                                ->first();
                        if (!empty($result)) {
                            $this->AccessControl->setUser($result->toArray(), false);
                            $this->Flash->set(__('You have successfuly logged in.'), ['element' => 'success']);
                            $this->redirect(['_name' => 'dashboard']);
                        } else {
                            $data = [];
                            $data['email'] = $user['email'];
                            $data['first_name'] = $user['givenName'];
                            $data['last_name'] = $user['familyName'];
                            $data['socialId'] = $user['id'];
                            $data['role_id'] = Configure::read('Role.loginWithGmailUserRole');
                            //$data matches my Users table
                            $entity = $usersTable->newEntity($data);
                            if ($usersTable->save($entity)) {
                                $data['id'] = $entity->id;
                                $this->AccessControl->setUser($data, false);
                                $this->Flash->set(__('You have successfuly logged in.'), ['element' => 'success']);
                                $this->redirect(['_name' => 'dashboard']);
                            } else {
                                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid login.'));
            //redirect to login action
                                $this->redirect(['_name' => 'account-login']);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->error(__('Your email is invalid for this application.'));
        //redirect to login action
                        $this->redirect(['_name' => 'account-login']);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Gmail infos not found.'));
        //redirect to login action
                    return $this->redirect(['_name' => 'account-login']);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Gmail error.'));
                return $this->redirect(['_name' => 'account-login']);
            }
        }
    }
```